# Is there a way to make a model method in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I was thinking to make a method that will give me the specific object from Active::Record::Associations::CollectionProxy.

For example, I have a user model that has many user_checklists and user_checklists belongs_to checklist model. So I want to make a method that will check the value in the checklist model and return the value from user_checklist model.

For example. 
checklists table has the following row

```
╔═════════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║         id          ║    name          ║
╠═════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║          1          ║ Complete MBA     ║
╠═════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║          2          ║ Painting class   ║
╚═════════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

and the users table has the following

```
╔═════════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║         id          ║    name          ║
╠═════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║          1          ║    name          ║
╚═════════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

and user_checklist has the following row

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║    id      ║    user_id ║ checklist_id  ║   completed   ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║     1      ║      1     ║      1        ║     true      ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║     2      ║      1     ║      2        ║     false     ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

So I was thinking to make a method called MBA in user_checklist that will give me the MBA completed value.

this is how I want to call
`user.first.user_checklists.mba.completed`

I don't know how to achieve this. Or I am thinking totally wrong here?

Comment: Do you need a method which returns whether the user completed a checklist(any checklist) or only specific value(MBA) @gsumk?

Comment: specefic value. In this case I wasted to the value just for `completed MBA` @Aarthi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest selecting only the id of the checklist.

```
scope :mba, -> { where(checklist_id: Checklist.where(name: "Completed MBA").pluck(:id) }
```

Will query only desired column(`id`) from the database(with a better performance),

```
 SELECT "checklists"."id" FROM "checklists" WHERE "checklists"."id" = $1
```

and you can get the same as what you did

```
User.first.user_checklists.mba.first&.completed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your scope to avoid N+1 Query:

```rb
scope :mba, -> { joins(:checklists).where('checklists.name = "Completed MBA"')
```

You don't need to select the first and the id in your scope because I guess you call `first` method on your next request :

`User.first.user_checklists.mba.first&.completed`

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out a way. On make a scope on user_checklists that look for mba_id and returns only that value form user_checkilust

```
scope :mba, -> { where(checklist_id: Checklist.where(name: "Completed MBA").first&.id) }
```

After that I was able to do

```
User.first.user_checklists.mba.first&.completed
```

So that works for me for now.